# Authenticate HTPPS using SSL having .crt file in c language

Tags: c, ssl, curl, https

Can any one tell me about the HTTPS authentication using ssl .I have a crt file .What are the files required to authenticate HTTPS . I am using CURl . Any example program in c language to authenticate HTPPS using CURl is highly appreciable..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html), and you've looked at the example [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplessl.html). That uses a PEM file: from the [docs](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTSSLCERTTYPE) for `CURLOPTSSLCERTTYPE`, the supported formats are PEM and DER: your CRT file might be in DER format, so try the code from the sample.

If you have a valid .crt client certificate that doesn't get successfully interpreted as a DER format file you can [convert it to PEM format](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html).